# Uniswap addLiquidity function transaction revert

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, uniswap

I try addLiquidity function but I result get transaction revert. I set deadline = block.timestamp and I use remix. Why transaction is revert? I found the problem line and specified it in code. I think

```
 pair = address(uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
                hex'ff',
                factory,
                keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1)),
                hex'96e8ac4277198ff8b6f785478aa9a39f403cb768dd02cbee326c3e7da348845f' // init code hash
            ))));
```

I think the 4th argument of this code is wrong. Whats mean init code hash ? and how can I find and verify the init code hash

Thank you

Txn hash
https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0xe2bcef8c4d4fc1732b4604a73caf6213d6e3f5e1a33151392458eccff384ddca

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0;

import './IUniswapV2Pair.sol';

import "./SafeMath.sol";

library UniswapV2Library {
    using SafeMath for uint;

    // returns sorted token addresses, used to handle return values from pairs sorted in this order
    function sortTokens(address tokenA, address tokenB) internal pure returns (address token0, address token1) {
        require(tokenA != tokenB, 'UniswapV2Library: IDENTICAL_ADDRESSES');
        (token0, token1) = tokenA < tokenB ? (tokenA, tokenB) : (tokenB, tokenA);
        require(token0 != address(0), 'UniswapV2Library: ZERO_ADDRESS');
    }

    // calculates the CREATE2 address for a pair without making any external calls
    function pairFor(address factory, address tokenA, address tokenB) internal pure returns (address pair) {
        (address token0, address token1) = sortTokens(tokenA, tokenB);
        pair = address(uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
                hex'ff',
                factory,
                keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1)),
                hex'96e8ac4277198ff8b6f785478aa9a39f403cb768dd02cbee326c3e7da348845f' // init code hash
            ))));
    }

    // fetches and sorts the reserves for a pair
    function getReserves(address factory, address tokenA, address tokenB) internal view returns (uint reserveA, uint reserveB) {
        (address token0,) = sortTokens(tokenA, tokenB);
        (uint reserve0, uint reserve1,) = IUniswapV2Pair(pairFor(factory, tokenA, tokenB)).getReserves();
        (reserveA, reserveB) = tokenA == token0 ? (reserve0, reserve1) : (reserve1, reserve0);
    }

    // given some amount of an asset and pair reserves, returns an equivalent amount of the other asset
    function quote(uint amountA, uint reserveA, uint reserveB) internal pure returns (uint amountB) {
        require(amountA > 0, 'UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_AMOUNT');
        require(reserveA > 0 && reserveB > 0, 'UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY');
        amountB = amountA.mul(reserveB) / reserveA;
    }

    // given an input amount of an asset and pair reserves, returns the maximum output amount of the other asset
    function getAmountOut(uint amountIn, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) internal pure returns (uint amountOut) {
        require(amountIn > 0, 'UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT');
        require(reserveIn > 0 && reserveOut > 0, 'UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY');
        uint amountInWithFee = amountIn.mul(997);
        uint numerator = amountInWithFee.mul(reserveOut);
        uint denominator = reserveIn.mul(1000).add(amountInWithFee);
        amountOut = numerator / denominator;
    }

    // given an output amount of an asset and pair reserves, returns a required input amount of the other asset
    function getAmountIn(uint amountOut, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) internal pure returns (uint amountIn) {
        require(amountOut > 0, 'UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT');
        require(reserveIn > 0 && reserveOut > 0, 'UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY');
        uint numerator = reserveIn.mul(amountOut).mul(1000);
        uint denominator = reserveOut.sub(amountOut).mul(997);
        amountIn = (numerator / denominator).add(1);
    }

    // performs chained getAmountOut calculations on any number of pairs
    function getAmountsOut(address factory, uint amountIn, address[] memory path) internal view returns (uint[] memory amounts) {
        require(path.length >= 2, 'UniswapV2Library: INVALID_PATH');
        amounts = new uint[](path.length);
        amounts[0] = amountIn;
        for (uint i; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
            (uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) = getReserves(factory, path[i], path[i + 1]);
            amounts[i + 1] = getAmountOut(amounts[i], reserveIn, reserveOut);
        }
    }

    // performs chained getAmountIn calculations on any number of pairs
    function getAmountsIn(address factory, uint amountOut, address[] memory path) internal view returns (uint[] memory amounts) {
        require(path.length >= 2, 'UniswapV2Library: INVALID_PATH');
        amounts = new uint[](path.length);
        amounts[amounts.length - 1] = amountOut;
        for (uint i = path.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            (uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) = getReserves(factory, path[i - 1], path[i]);
            amounts[i - 1] = getAmountIn(amounts[i], reserveIn, reserveOut);
        }
    }
}
```

this is router contract

```
pragma solidity =0.6.6;

import './IUniswapV2Factory.sol';
import './TransferHelper.sol';
import './IUniswapV2Pair.sol';
import './IUniswapV2Router02.sol';
import './UniswapV2Library.sol';
import './SafeMath.sol';
import './IERC20.sol';
import './IWETH.sol';

contract UniswapV2Router02 is IUniswapV2Router02 {
    using SafeMath for uint;

    address public immutable override factory;
    address public immutable override WETH;

    modifier ensure(uint deadline) {
        deadline = block.timestamp;
        require(deadline >= block.timestamp, 'UniswapV2Router: EXPIRED');
        _;
    }

    constructor(address _factory, address _WETH) public {
        factory = _factory;
        WETH = _WETH;
    }

    receive() external payable {
        assert(msg.sender == WETH); // only accept ETH via fallback from the WETH contract
    }

    // **** ADD LIQUIDITY ****
    function _addLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint amountADesired,
        uint amountBDesired,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin
    ) internal virtual returns (uint amountA, uint amountB) {
        // create the pair if it doesn't exist yet
        if (IUniswapV2Factory(factory).getPair(tokenA, tokenB) == address(0)) {
            IUniswapV2Factory(factory).createPair(tokenA, tokenB);
        }
        (uint reserveA, uint reserveB) = UniswapV2Library.getReserves(factory, tokenA, tokenB);
        if (reserveA == 0 && reserveB == 0) {
            (amountA, amountB) = (amountADesired, amountBDesired);
        } else {
            uint amountBOptimal = UniswapV2Library.quote(amountADesired, reserveA, reserveB);
            if (amountBOptimal <= amountBDesired) {
                require(amountBOptimal >= amountBMin, 'UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_B_AMOUNT');
                (amountA, amountB) = (amountADesired, amountBOptimal);
            } else {
                uint amountAOptimal = UniswapV2Library.quote(amountBDesired, reserveB, reserveA);
                assert(amountAOptimal <= amountADesired);
                require(amountAOptimal >= amountAMin, 'UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_A_AMOUNT');
                (amountA, amountB) = (amountAOptimal, amountBDesired);
            }
        }
    }
    function addLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint amountADesired,
        uint amountBDesired,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external virtual override ensure(deadline) returns (uint amountA, uint amountB, uint liquidity) {
        deadline = block.timestamp;
        (amountA, amountB) = _addLiquidity(tokenA, tokenB, amountADesired, amountBDesired, amountAMin, amountBMin);
//---------------------PROBLEM İS HERE--------------------------------/
            address pair = UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, tokenA, tokenB); 
//---------------------PROBLEM İS HERE--------------------------------/
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(tokenA, msg.sender, pair, amountA);
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(tokenB, msg.sender, pair, amountB);
        liquidity = IUniswapV2Pair(pair).mint(to);
    }
    
     
    function addLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint amountTokenDesired,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external virtual override payable ensure(deadline) returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity) {
        deadline = block.timestamp;
        (amountToken, amountETH) = _addLiquidity(
            token,
            WETH,
            amountTokenDesired,
            msg.value,
            amountTokenMin,
            amountETHMin
        );
        address pair = UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, token, WETH);
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(token, msg.sender, pair, amountToken);
        IWETH(WETH).deposit{value: amountETH}();
        assert(IWETH(WETH).transfer(pair, amountETH));
        liquidity = IUniswapV2Pair(pair).mint(to);
        // refund dust eth, if any
        if (msg.value > amountETH) TransferHelper.safeTransferETH(msg.sender, msg.value - amountETH);
    }

    // **** REMOVE LIQUIDITY ****
    function removeLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) public virtual override ensure(deadline) returns (uint amountA, uint amountB) {
        address pair = UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, tokenA, tokenB);
        IUniswapV2Pair(pair).transferFrom(msg.sender, pair, liquidity); // send liquidity to pair
        (uint amount0, uint amount1) = IUniswapV2Pair(pair).burn(to);
        (address token0,) = UniswapV2Library.sortTokens(tokenA, tokenB);
        (amountA, amountB) = tokenA == token0 ? (amount0, amount1) : (amount1, amount0);
        require(amountA >= amountAMin, 'UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_A_AMOUNT');
        require(amountB >= amountBMin, 'UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_B_AMOUNT');
    }
    function removeLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) public virtual override ensure(deadline) returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH) {
        (amountToken, amountETH) = removeLiquidity(
            token,
            WETH,
            liquidity,
            amountTokenMin,
            amountETHMin,
            address(this),
            deadline
        );
        TransferHelper.safeTransfer(token, to, amountToken);
        IWETH(WETH).withdraw(amountETH);
        TransferHelper.safeTransferETH(to, amountETH);
    }
    function removeLiquidityWithPermit(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external virtual override returns (uint amountA, uint amountB) {
        address pair = UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, tokenA, tokenB);
        uint value = approveMax ? uint(-1) : liquidity;
        IUniswapV2Pair(pair).permit(msg.sender, address(this), value, deadline, v, r, s);
        (amountA, amountB) = removeLiquidity(tokenA, tokenB, liquidity, amountAMin, amountBMin, to, deadline);
    }
    function removeLiquidityETHWithPermit(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external virtual override returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH) {
        address pair = UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, token, WETH);
        uint value = approveMax ? uint(-1) : liquidity;
        IUniswapV2Pair(pair).permit(msg.sender, address(this), value, deadline, v, r, s);
        (amountToken, amountETH) = removeLiquidityETH(token, liquidity, amountTokenMin, amountETHMin, to, deadline);
    }

    // **** REMOVE LIQUIDITY (supporting fee-on-transfer tokens) ****
    function removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) public virtual override ensure(deadline) returns (uint amountETH) {
        (, amountETH) = removeLiquidity(
            token,
            WETH,
            liquidity,
            amountTokenMin,
            amountETHMin,
            address(this),
            deadline
        );
        TransferHelper.safeTransfer(token, to, IERC20(token).balanceOf(address(this)));
        IWETH(WETH).withdraw(amountETH);
        TransferHelper.safeTransferETH(to, amountETH);
    }
    function removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external virtual override returns (uint amountETH) {
        address pair = UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, token, WETH);
        uint value = approveMax ? uint(-1) : liquidity;
        IUniswapV2Pair(pair).permit(msg.sender, address(this), value, deadline, v, r, s);
        amountETH = removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            token, liquidity, amountTokenMin, amountETHMin, to, deadline
        );
    }
/*
    // **** SWAP ****
    // requires the initial amount to have already been sent to the first pair
    function _swap(uint[] memory amounts, address[] memory path, address _to) internal virtual {
        for (uint i; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
            (address input, address output) = (path[i], path[i + 1]);
            (address token0,) = UniswapV2Library.sortTokens(input, output);
            uint amountOut = amounts[i + 1];
            (uint amount0Out, uint amount1Out) = input == token0 ? (uint(0), amountOut) : (amountOut, uint(0));
            address to = i < path.length - 2 ? UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, output, path[i + 2]) : _to;
            IUniswapV2Pair(UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, input, output)).swap(
                amount0Out, amount1Out, to, new bytes(0)
            );
        }
    }

    function swapExactTokensForTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external virtual override ensure(deadline) returns (uint[] memory amounts) {
        amounts = UniswapV2Library.getAmountsOut(factory, amountIn, path);
        require(amounts[amounts.length - 1] >= amountOutMin, 'UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT');
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(
            path[0], msg.sender, UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, path[0], path[1]), amounts[0]
        );
        _swap(amounts, path, to);
    }
    function swapTokensForExactTokens(
        uint amountOut,
        uint amountInMax,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external virtual override ensure(deadline) returns (uint[] memory amounts) {
        amounts = UniswapV2Library.getAmountsIn(factory, amountOut, path);
        require(amounts[0] <= amountInMax, 'UniswapV2Router: EXCESSIVE_INPUT_AMOUNT');
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(
            path[0], msg.sender, UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, path[0], path[1]), amounts[0]
        );
        _swap(amounts, path, to);
    }
    function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        virtual
        override
        payable
        ensure(deadline)
        returns (uint[] memory amounts)
    {
        require(path[0] == WETH, 'UniswapV2Router: INVALID_PATH');
        amounts = UniswapV2Library.getAmountsOut(factory, msg.value, path);
        require(amounts[amounts.length - 1] >= amountOutMin, 'UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT');
        IWETH(WETH).deposit{value: amounts[0]}();
        assert(IWETH(WETH).transfer(UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, path[0], path[1]), amounts[0]));
        _swap(amounts, path, to);
    }
    function swapTokensForExactETH(uint amountOut, uint amountInMax, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        virtual
        override
        ensure(deadline)
        returns (uint[] memory amounts)
    {
        require(path[path.length - 1] == WETH, 'UniswapV2Router: INVALID_PATH');
        amounts = UniswapV2Library.getAmountsIn(factory, amountOut, path);
        require(amounts[0] <= amountInMax, 'UniswapV2Router: EXCESSIVE_INPUT_AMOUNT');
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(
            path[0], msg.sender, UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, path[0], path[1]), amounts[0]
        );
        _swap(amounts, path, address(this));
        IWETH(WETH).withdraw(amounts[amounts.length - 1]);
        TransferHelper.safeTransferETH(to, amounts[amounts.length - 1]);
    }
    function swapExactTokensForETH(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        virtual
        override
        ensure(deadline)
        returns (uint[] memory amounts)
    {
        require(path[path.length - 1] == WETH, 'UniswapV2Router: INVALID_PATH');
        amounts = UniswapV2Library.getAmountsOut(factory, amountIn, path);
        require(amounts[amounts.length - 1] >= amountOutMin, 'UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT');
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(
            path[0], msg.sender, UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, path[0], path[1]), amounts[0]
        );
        _swap(amounts, path, address(this));
        IWETH(WETH).withdraw(amounts[amounts.length - 1]);
        TransferHelper.safeTransferETH(to, amounts[amounts.length - 1]);
    }
    function swapETHForExactTokens(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        virtual
        override
        payable
        ensure(deadline)
        returns (uint[] memory amounts)
    {
        require(path[0] == WETH, 'UniswapV2Router: INVALID_PATH');
        amounts = UniswapV2Library.getAmountsIn(factory, amountOut, path);
        require(amounts[0] <= msg.value, 'UniswapV2Router: EXCESSIVE_INPUT_AMOUNT');
        IWETH(WETH).deposit{value: amounts[0]}();
        assert(IWETH(WETH).transfer(UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, path[0], path[1]), amounts[0]));
        _swap(amounts, path, to);
        // refund dust eth, if any
        if (msg.value > amounts[0]) TransferHelper.safeTransferETH(msg.sender, msg.value - amounts[0]);
    }

    // **** SWAP (supporting fee-on-transfer tokens) ****
    // requires the initial amount to have already been sent to the first pair
    function _swapSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(address[] memory path, address _to) internal virtual {
        for (uint i; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
            (address input, address output) = (path[i], path[i + 1]);
            (address token0,) = UniswapV2Library.sortTokens(input, output);
            IUniswapV2Pair pair = IUniswapV2Pair(UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, input, output));
            uint amountInput;
            uint amountOutput;
            { // scope to avoid stack too deep errors
            (uint reserve0, uint reserve1,) = pair.getReserves();
            (uint reserveInput, uint reserveOutput) = input == token0 ? (reserve0, reserve1) : (reserve1, reserve0);
            amountInput = IERC20(input).balanceOf(address(pair)).sub(reserveInput);
            amountOutput = UniswapV2Library.getAmountOut(amountInput, reserveInput, reserveOutput);
            }
            (uint amount0Out, uint amount1Out) = input == token0 ? (uint(0), amountOutput) : (amountOutput, uint(0));
            address to = i < path.length - 2 ? UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, output, path[i + 2]) : _to;
            pair.swap(amount0Out, amount1Out, to, new bytes(0));
        }
    }
    function swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external virtual override ensure(deadline) {
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(
            path[0], msg.sender, UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, path[0], path[1]), amountIn
        );
        uint balanceBefore = IERC20(path[path.length - 1]).balanceOf(to);
        _swapSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(path, to);
        require(
            IERC20(path[path.length - 1]).balanceOf(to).sub(balanceBefore) >= amountOutMin,
            'UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT'
        );
    }
    function swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    )
        external
        virtual
        override
        payable
        ensure(deadline)
    {
        require(path[0] == WETH, 'UniswapV2Router: INVALID_PATH');
        uint amountIn = msg.value;
        IWETH(WETH).deposit{value: amountIn}();
        assert(IWETH(WETH).transfer(UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, path[0], path[1]), amountIn));
        uint balanceBefore = IERC20(path[path.length - 1]).balanceOf(to);
        _swapSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(path, to);
        require(
            IERC20(path[path.length - 1]).balanceOf(to).sub(balanceBefore) >= amountOutMin,
            'UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT'
        );
    }

    function swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    )
        external
        virtual
        override
        ensure(deadline)
    {
        require(path[path.length - 1] == WETH, 'UniswapV2Router: INVALID_PATH');
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(
            path[0], msg.sender, UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, path[0], path[1]), amountIn
        );
        _swapSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(path, address(this));
        uint amountOut = IERC20(WETH).balanceOf(address(this));
        require(amountOut >= amountOutMin, 'UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT');
        IWETH(WETH).withdraw(amountOut);
        TransferHelper.safeTransferETH(to, amountOut);
    }
*/
    // **** LIBRARY FUNCTIONS ****
    function quote(uint amountA, uint reserveA, uint reserveB) public pure virtual override returns (uint amountB) {
        return UniswapV2Library.quote(amountA, reserveA, reserveB);
    }

    function getAmountOut(uint amountIn, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut)
        public
        pure
        virtual
        override
        returns (uint amountOut)
    {
        return UniswapV2Library.getAmountOut(amountIn, reserveIn, reserveOut);
    }

    function getAmountIn(uint amountOut, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut)
        public
        pure
        virtual
        override
        returns (uint amountIn)
    {
        return UniswapV2Library.getAmountIn(amountOut, reserveIn, reserveOut);
    }

    function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path)
        public
        view
        virtual
        override
        returns (uint[] memory amounts)
    {
        return UniswapV2Library.getAmountsOut(factory, amountIn, path);
    }

    function getAmountsIn(uint amountOut, address[] memory path)
        public
        view
        virtual
        override
        returns (uint[] memory amounts)
    {
        return UniswapV2Library.getAmountsIn(factory, amountOut, path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get `hex'96e8ac4277198ff8b6f785478aa9a39f403cb768dd02cbee326c3e7da348845f'` from, or how exactly did you compute this value?

Comment: I just tried fork Uniswap. This is the default Uniswap contract code. I don't changed this hex value. I don't know how computed. How can I compute or find this

Comment: original code 
link is here                                                                                                                                            
                                                                             
https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/libraries/UniswapV2Library.sol

Comment: Did you find the solution to this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 12):

You need to create the `init_code_hash` using your newly deployed Factory contract.

This address hard-coded in Uniswap's Github repo is specifically for their deployment in Ethereum networks.

In your `UniswapV2Factory.sol` code, add the following piece of code.

```
bytes32 public constant INIT_CODE_PAIR_HASH = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(type(UniswapV2Pair).creationCode));
```

Once it's deployed, use remix or truffle console to call this to get the value. Then substitute this value into your `UniswapV2Library` before deploying the router.

Comment: any way to know this init_code_hash off-chain before deployment?

Answer (score 1):

This init code hash is calculated like this:

`keccak256(abi.encodePacked(type(PairContract).creationCode));`

Answer (score 0):

It use to compute address generated by CREATE2. See: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1014. init code is bytecode of contract UniswapV2Pair. init code hash is keccak256(init code).

Answer (score 0):

This codehash is created using the UniswapV2Factory function `pairCodeHash()`