# Uniswap Router V2 Deployment AddLiquidity()

Tags: solidity, remix, uniswap

I'm getting an error on the `addLiquidity()` method of Uniswap's Router (`UniswapV2Router02.sol`) using my own deployed version of the contract on a testnet. I'm using Remix, and am receiving the message: `"Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }"`

For testing purposes, I've created two ERC20 tokens, let's call them TOK1, TOK2.

I minted myself 100 of TOK1 and 100 of TOK2

I called the approve function on both TOK1 and TOK2 contract with my wallet address

I compiled + deployed the Uniswap Factory (`UniswapV2Factory`) as well as the `UniswapV2Router02`

I set up the Router (`init()` method) by providing the Factory address that I deployed (above), and the address of TOK1 (also above).

I then try to call the `addLiquidity(..)` method with the following parameters:

```
tokenA = TOK1 address
tokenB = TOK2 address
amountADesired = 1 (in wei => 1000000000000000000)
amountBDesired = 1 (in wei => 1000000000000000000)
amountAMin = 0.1 (in wei => 100000000000000000)
amountBMin = 0.1 (in wei => 100000000000000000)
to: my wallet address
deadline: unix timestamp + 20 minutes
```

This results in the above gas estimation error message from Remix. I've tried changing the Gas limits as well as the `Value` field in the `Deploy & Run Transactions` window of Remix. Neither seems to have any effect.

Is there something that needs to be done first?

Comment: Check if the init code hash in the UniswapV2Library is correct:

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/88075/uniswap-addliquidity-function-transaction-revert

Comment: You saved me! I've been messing around with this for about 6 hours today and the answer was that init code hash piece. If you want to provide an answer with this as the solution, I'll select it.

Comment: I suffered for the same reason for days too...just rewrote the comment as answer however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that the init code hash in the UniswapV2Library is incorrect:
[Uniswap addLiquidity function transaction revert](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/88075/uniswap-addliquidity-function-transaction-revert)