# gas estimation fail when call addLiquidity from UniswapV2Router02.sol contract

Tags: uniswap, brownie

I am trying to deploy uniswap V2 contracts using brownie but
I have always an error when I call addLiquidity on UniswapV2Router02.sol
Waht I did so far:

1.- Deploy UniswapV2Factory.sol

```
def deploy_factory():
contract_factory = UniswapV2Factory.deploy(
    get_account(account="main"),
    {"from": get_account(account="main"), "gas_price": get_gas_price() * 1.5},
    publish_source=config["networks"][network.show_active()].get("verify"),
)
```

2.- Deploy my custom WETH.

```
pragma solidity 0.7.5;
```

// solhint-disable
contract WETH {
string public name = "Wrapped Ether";
string public symbol = "WETH";
uint8 public decimals = 18;

```
event Approval(address indexed src, address indexed guy, uint wad);
event Transfer(address indexed src, address indexed dst, uint wad);
event Deposit(address indexed dst, uint wad);
event Withdrawal(address indexed src, uint wad);

mapping(address => uint) public balanceOf;
mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowance;

receive() external payable {
    deposit();
}

function deposit() public payable {
    balanceOf[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    emit Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value);
}

function withdraw(uint wad) public {
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= wad);
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= wad;
    msg.sender.transfer(wad);
    emit Withdrawal(msg.sender, wad);
}

function totalSupply() public view returns (uint) {
    return address(this).balance;
}

function approve(address guy, uint wad) public returns (bool) {
    allowance[msg.sender][guy] = wad;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, guy, wad);
    return true;
}

function transfer(address dst, uint wad) public returns (bool) {
    return transferFrom(msg.sender, dst, wad);
}

function transferFrom(
    address src,
    address dst,
    uint wad
) public returns (bool) {
    require(balanceOf[src] >= wad);

    if (src != msg.sender && allowance[src][msg.sender] != uint(-1)) {
        require(allowance[src][msg.sender] >= wad);
        allowance[src][msg.sender] -= wad;
    }

    balanceOf[src] -= wad;
    balanceOf[dst] += wad;

    emit Transfer(src, dst, wad);

    return true;
}
```

}

3.- Deploy UniswapV2Router.sol

```
def deploy_router():
contract = UniswapV2Router02.deploy(
    factory.address,
    weth.address,
    {"from": get_account(account="main"), "gas_price": get_gas_price() * 1.5},
    publish_source=config["networks"][network.show_active()].get("verify"),
)
```

4.- Approve 2 erc20 tokens (usdt,usdc)(from aave facucet)

5.- Check tokens are approved in etherscan OK

5.- Create new pair on factory

```
def create_pair():
contract_factory = UniswapV2Factory[-1]
tx = contract_factory.createPair(
    USDT_ADDRESS,
    USDC_ADDRESS,
    {"from": get_account(account="main"), "gas_price": get_gas_price() * 1.5},
)
tx.wait(1)
```

6.- Add liquidity:

```
def add_liquidity():
contract = UniswapV2Router02[-1]
tx = contract.addLiquidity(
    USDT_ADDRESS,
    USDC_ADDRESS,
    10 * 10**6,
    10 * 10**6,
    0,
    0,
    get_account(account="main"),
    datetime.datetime.now().timestamp() + 60 * 60,
    {"from": get_account(account="main"), "gas_price": get_gas_price() * 1.5},
)
```

I always get gas estimator fail.
Do you know what i am doing wrong or how can I debug this error cuz brownie is not tellig me what is wrong??

Thanks.

Comment: Found the solution in this answer to other post:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/88075/uniswap-addliquidity-function-transaction-revert